# Ionic React, error "Argument of type is not assignable" for correct code

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework

I have some error messages. For exclude code problem I found this error with a standard app. When I use "blank", "sidemenu", "tabs" everething is ok. But when start "conference" and then run, I have error message:

> TypeScript error in /home/stdt/src/components/Map.tsx(15,39):
>   [react-scripts] Argument of type 'HTMLDivElement | null' is not
>   assignable to parameter of type 'Element'.  [react-scripts]   Type
>   'null' is not assignable to type 'Element'.  TS2345  [react-scripts]
>   13 |   useEffect(() => {  [react-scripts]
>   14 |  [react-scripts]
>   15 |     map.current = new google.maps.Map(mapEle.current, {
>   [react-scripts]                            ^

The similar problem in some other apps. This code from examples, so there are no code problem. 
What should I do, install something or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have had the same problem. The two 'solutions' I have found are:

1. Add a line to tsconfig.json:

```
    "strictNullChecks": false,
```

2. In src/components/Map.tsx place `if (mapEle && mapEle.current) {` and `}` around the uses of mapEle:

```
    if (mapEle && mapEle.current) {
       map.current = new google.maps.Map(mapEle.current, {
          center: {
            lat: mapCenter.lat,
            lng: mapCenter.lng
          },
          zoom: 16
       });


       addMarkers();

       google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map.current, 'idle', () => {
         if (mapEle.current) {
           mapEle.current.classList.add('show-map');
         }
       });
     }
```